# Appropriate closing of asyncio process without leaving it in zombie state

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, coroutine, zombie-process

In my program I start several asyncio.Process processes (using `create_subprocess_exec` method) and I want to be able to prevent them staying in zombie state upon termination. I tried to use child_watcher.add_child_handler (`asyncio.event_loop_policy.child_watcher`) method to apply termination callback to the process, but the problem is that the callback can not be a coroutine and inside the callback I need to await `proc.wait()` to make sure that the process is not left in zombie state. Could you please let me know if there is a flaw in my thinking or there is some other way to achieve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> ...`proc.wait()` to make sure that the process is not left in zombie state. Could you please let me know if there is a flaw in my thinking or there is some other way to achieve that?

You shouldn't need to use child watchers for this. Yes, you need to execute `proc.wait()` to ensure that the process doesn't remain a zombie, but you don't really need to *await* it, you can leave it in the background using `create_task()`. For example:

```py
proc = asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(...)
# run proc.wait() "in the background", ensuring the process is reaped
# as soon as it's done
asyncio.create_task(proc.wait())
... continue using proc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the zombie processes and infinite `wait`/`communicate` was the result of incorrect configuring of new `asyncio` loops in tests. It can be demonstrated by the following code.

```
import asyncio
from asyncio.subprocess import PIPE

async def main():
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        'echo', '42', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    print('pid', process.pid)
    stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()
    print('stdout', stdout)
    print('stderr', stderr)

if __name__  == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    # effective loop is not set to current context
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()  
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

This code hangs on `await process.communicate()`. If you `ps` the PID it looks like:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
18399 pts/3    Z+     0:00 [echo] <defunct>
```

To fix it, it's sufficient to add missing `set_event_loop` call which will set child watchers (see some historic details about `asyncio.get_child_watcher().attach_loop(loop)` [here](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/281)). If the previous loop wasn't set, asyncio raises:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot add child handler, the child watcher does not have a loop attached
```

Also note that if you don't need to interact with the `asyncio` loop instance directly, you can just use [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) which does all the needed setup and teardown behind the scenes.